# Converting an array, slice or vector to base58 encoding WITH check

Tags: rust, base58

I'm writing a code that converts an array/slice/vector to a B58-encoded string with the **check**. Here is the relevant code excerpt:

```
use bs58;
i = b"Hello"; // or
i = [0,1,2,3]; // or
i = vec![0,1,2,3];
let e = bs58::encode(i).with_check().into_string();
```

No matter what type I supply to bs58::encode(), it errors out saying that **method with_check() not found**. Coming from Python, it's really frustrating because I have to spend hours debugging simple stuff that should just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the API documentation for [bs58::encode](https://docs.rs/bs58/0.4.0/bs58/fn.encode.html), you see that it returns a [EncodeBuilder](https://docs.rs/bs58/0.4.0/bs58/encode/struct.EncodeBuilder.html).

Looking at the documentation for that, you see that there is a [`with_check`](https://docs.rs/bs58/0.4.0/bs58/encode/struct.EncodeBuilder.html#method.with_check) method but it has a note attached to it:

> This is supported on crate feature check only.

Rust supports crates defining optional features - these features typically have extra dependancies that are not needed in all cases, so they are off by default.

You can enable the extra features in your `Cargo.toml` file, like this:

```
[dependancies]
bs58 = { version="0.4.0", features=["check"] }
```

See also the [Features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) section of the Cargo book.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! The learning curve for Rust is taking a lot longer than I thought :)